# cancel default controller action's redirect

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, redirect, respond-to

There's this link:

```
= link_to "Close", close_ticket_path(:id => ticket.id), :onclick => $(this).closest('tr').remove()", :remote => true
```

which routes to tickets_controller#close:

```
  def close
    @ticket  = Ticket.find(params[:id]).update_attribute(:status, "closed")
  end
```

By default, this action will redirect to `views/tickets/close`. **How to disable this default redirect?** I know how to specify custom redirect, but this is not what I need. The view is managed by the script and the db is modified in the action, so no more action is needed and I don't want the page to refresh. `render` won't work neither, as the content in question is loaded dynamically, so basically doing precisely nothing is what I need.

I found this workaround to e.g. include `respond_to :js` and create empty `close.js.erb` file, or to move above `:onclick` to this file, but I want to do it idiomatically. As a matter of fact, the link works now as desired with the `respond_to :js` in the action (not included here), but console throws Missing template error, which is not very nice. I looked in [Rails Redirecting](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html), in [JS with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html), [Rendering guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html), and some more, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, after [reading this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render), I must do the justice and post the officially recommended way of handling this case. The action should read:

```
def close
  @ticket  = Ticket.find(params[:id]).update_attribute(:status, "closed")
  head :ok
end
```

Thank you, @auL5agoi, for leading me to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
def close
  @ticket  = Ticket.find(params[:id]).update_attribute(:status, "closed")
  render nothing: true, :status => 200
end
```

Comment: Oops, seems as if I [missed a spot](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render). Thank you :)